# SEO: hreflang is not working correctly - how can I fix it?

Tags: html, .htaccess, search, seo, href

My Website is

```
www.mydomain.net
```

I have the content in 2 languages, German and English.

Depending on the users country, "mydomain.net" will automatically redirect to:

```
www.mydomain.net/de
```

or

```
www.mydomain.net/en
```

I'm using these href-lang tags:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="mydomain.net/en"/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="mydomain.net/de"/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="mydomain.net/en"/>
```

**Expected result**

If a German user googles "mydomain.net", it should display the German content (Meta-Description etc.) of the website.

If an English user googles "mydomain.net", it should display the English content (Meta-Description etc.) of the website.

However this isn't working correctly at the moment.

**Actual result**

When a German user Googles "mydomain.net", he gets the English result. The English meta description will get displayed. Shouldn't google display the German result?

However if a German user Googles for example something like this "mydomain.net Kontakt" (includes a German word) it will display the German result as expected.

Comment: Anything here? https://www.google.come/search?q=hreflang%20seo

Comment: I have already checked different websites, unfortunately I couldn't fix it with that information.

Comment: Btw., the HTML of your home page shows different URLs (`/en` instead of `?lang=en`).  -- You might get better help on [webmasters.se] (flag your question and ask a moderator to migrate it).

Comment: yes thats true, today i changed the urls with mod_rewrite only for SEO, but it shouldn't be a problem. Sorry I will update my question!

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it's not working"? What is happening that shouldn't, or what is it that should happen but is not happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto-redirection is generally a bad idea. If a bot is auto-redirected then it may not be able to discover all your content. You're also using cookies to store the user's content preference.

What I'd recommend is:

1. rufsam.com (your homepage) can auto-redirect to /en or /de but /en
   and /de pages should never redirect (you are currently redirecting them
   based on cookie)
2. Use rufsam.com (your homepage) as the href for x-default. Google's documentation says x-default should be used for pages that redirect.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! My /de or /en pages aren't redirecting to somewhere, or am I missing something?

Comment: When I tried accessing your /de page from here in the US it redirected me to /en